# fancybox - passing 'this' to onClosed function

Tags: jquery, function, fancybox

Hi this is probly really simple but I juast cant seem to figure it out!

```
if( is_logged_out( html ) ) {
    var throughClick = $(this);
    $.fancybox( html, { 
        'autoDimensions' : false,
        'width' : 'auto', 
        'height' : 'auto', 
        'transitionIn' : 'none', 
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'hideOnOverlayClick' : false, 
        'showCloseButton' : false, 
        'onClosed' : 
        function( throughClick ) {
            alert(throughClick.attr('name'));
            throughClick.trigger('click');      
        }
    });
}else{
```

All i want to do is pass the object of whichever button or link that was clicked, so once the user has logged back in it will process again.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

onClosed:function() {
console.log(arguments)
}

would lead you to orig :P that should have the origional element clicked

arguments[2].orig.hide() would hide the link clicked

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you fix the 'whichever button or link' object in the `throughClick` variable.  That's not necessarily done by the `this` variable.  `this` is filled in by the calling function, which you don't always control, especially not when using

Probably, you better tell the object to call a function explicitly when clicked.  This can be easily automated by enumerating them:

```
var onclickables = $.map
     ( ["#clickme1","#clickme2"]
     , function( i, e ) { return $(i); } 
     );

var html="";// whatever you need it to be

$.each(onclickables)( function( index, item ) {
    item.click( function(e){
       your_new_function( html, item ); // <=== here you know the object
    });
});


function your_new_function( html, throughClick ) {
  if( is_logged_out( html ) ) {          
      $.fancybox( html, { 
          'autoDimensions' : false,
          'width' : 'auto', 
          'height' : 'auto', 
          'transitionIn' : 'none', 
          'transitionOut' : 'none',
          'hideOnOverlayClick' : false, 
          'showCloseButton' : false, 
          'onClosed' : 
          function( throughClick ) {
              alert(throughClick.attr('name'));
              throughClick.trigger('click');      
          }
      });
```

I showed the idea in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtofl/5PZrc/1/), too.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem does not lie with $(this). Going back to my original post and replacing `var throughClick = $(this);` with `var throughClick = 'foobar'` and then trying to echo out **through fancybox** the problem remains.